# Delete Objects in JavaScript. I'm a bit confused.I have a problem with removeName(person)

Tags: javascript, object

I'm a bit confused with JavaScript's `delete` operator.I am begginer in JS and I have a problem with `removeName(person)`. Take the following piece of code:

```
let user = {};
user.name = "name";


export default function removeName (person){

  delete user.name;
  return new Object(person)


}

removeName(user);
console.log(user);
```

After this piece of code has been executed,I take as output `{}` but I want the below the function

`removeName (person)`, accept the person object as a parameter, and
modifies the person object by deleting the property name field. THE
function will not return anything, it will modify the object directly.

I'm a bit confused because I think that i solve but I do not get the result I need.

Comment: "*THE function will not return anything, it will modify the object directly.*" Then why `return new Object()`...?

Comment: Putting aside that `user` and `person` are both references to the very same object (ie they are pointing at the same location in memory, thus if you modify one you also modify the other), if you want to modify `person` then why do you `delete user.name` ?

Comment: @derpirscher Because I was asked the following : the function
removeName (person), accept the person object as a parameter, and
modifies the person object **by deleting the property name field**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two big differences between the expectations you have described and your code:

- you remove a property from `user`, which is the same object that you pass in this specific case, but if you passed something else, your current `function` would incorrectly remove `user`'s name even if you intended to remove the `name` of another object
- your function returns a value, while you stated that it's not your intention

```js
let user = {};
user.name = "name";


function removeName (person){

  delete person.name;

}

removeName(user);
console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `user` and the `person` are the same object in the heap(they have the same reference/pointer). So if you would like to remove property only for `person` object in function you need to create a copy of this object and remove there.
If you need a function not to return anything - just removing the `person` property - try this:

```
let user = {};
user.name = "name";


export default function removeName (person){
  let copy = Object.assign({}, person);
  delete copy.name;

}

removeName(user);
console.log(user);
```